# static_cast of "this" to another base class

Tags: c++, constructor, multiple-inheritance, downcast, static-cast

Is the following use of static_cast in a constructor "safe"?

For context I'm experimenting with a Win32 window wrapper using a policy-based design.  Part of it involves creating a dispatcher class by inheriting from a base dispatcher that holds a map of messages to functions, and then also deriving from various message crackers, which will each add one or more handlers to the base class dispatcher.  I would like to do this without requiring any further plumbing, i.e. for each message type to add handlers in their own constructors rather than manually having to do it in the dispatcher's constructor.

I think I'm correct in saying that *Dispatcher_Base* is guaranteed to be constructed before *Message_Type_1* and *Message_Type_2*, so when their constructors are called, the static_cast will return me a valid object from "this".  However it smells pretty bad, so I'm wondering if I've made a huge error in the basic premise.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename dispatcher_type>
class Message_Type_1
{
public:

    Message_Type_1()
    {
        auto * dispatcher = static_cast<dispatcher_type *>(this);

        dispatcher->Add_Handler(1);
    }

    virtual ~Message_Type_1() = default;
};

template<typename dispatcher_type>
class Message_Type_2
{
public:

    Message_Type_2()
    {
        auto * dispatcher = static_cast<dispatcher_type *>(this);

        dispatcher->Add_Handler(2);
    }

    virtual ~Message_Type_2() = default;
};

class Dispatcher_Base
{
public:

    Dispatcher_Base()
    {

    }

    void Add_Handler(int x)
    {
        listeners.push_back(x);
    }

    std::vector<int> const & Get_Listeners() const
    {
        return listeners;
    }

    virtual ~Dispatcher_Base() = default;

private:

    std::vector<int> listeners;
};

class Dispatcher_Derived :  public Dispatcher_Base,
                            public Message_Type_1<Dispatcher_Derived>,
                            public Message_Type_2<Dispatcher_Derived>
{
public:

    Dispatcher_Derived() = default;

    virtual ~Dispatcher_Derived() = default;
};

int main(void)
{
    Dispatcher_Derived dispatcher;

    auto const & listeners = dispatcher.Get_Listeners();

    std::cout << "There are " << listeners.size() << " listeners in the set." << std::endl;

    for (auto i : listeners)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to inherit from `Message_Type_1<Dispatcher_Base>` instead of `Message_Type_1<Dispatcher_Derived>` in your example?

Comment: Well you would think that (and indeed I did at first) but in fact that gives me a compile error.  It worked with Dispatcher_Derived, so I went with that without fully understanding why.

Comment: Well, as the code is written now the `static_cast` is definitely UB because in the constructor of `Message_Type_1` there definitely does not exist an object of type `Dispatcher_Derived` yet because in order to create a `Dispatcher_Derived` you must first create a `Message_Type_1`.

Comment: But `Dispatcher_Base` does exist, which is where the `Add_Handler` function is to be found.  Code smell aside, I'm kind-of interested that it works ok in both GCC and MSVC.

Comment: It is not code smell, it is undefined behavior. And you have to stretch the definition of "works in GCC" a bit because if you run it with `-fsanitize=undefined,address` it produces `runtime error: downcast of address 0x7fffffffe540 which does not point to an object of type 'Dispatcher_Derived'`.

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced.  Thanks.